# Flutter - Get String and Set Value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
Text(welcome)
```

Where 'welcome' is a String from another page.

```
 String welcome = "Welcome"
```

Basic. But what I would like was to be able to request some value of this String for example the username that way when using the String 'welcome' I should pass the value 'username'.

It is possible?

Comment: It's really hard to know what you mean, so I just guessed with my answer.  Please elaborate a bit more to make your problem clearer. It would be good with a bit more code to show what you're stuck at, and what the end result should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation as follows:

```
Text("$welcome $username")
```

Where:

```
String welcome = "Welcome";
String username = "dnnx";
```

So the widget would say: "Welcome dnnx"

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not sure... Are you asking about string concatenation?
If so, you can do this by:

1. Using plus operator:

```
  String welcome = 'Welcome';
  String userName = 'Tom';
  String space = ' ';
  
  String concatenated = welcome + space+ userName;
  
  print(concatenated);
```

2. By string interpolation:

```
  String welcome = 'Welcome';
  String userName = 'Tom';
  print ('$welcome $userName');
```

Comment: I wanted something similar to widgets that might require some value. Like: const TextInputWithIcon(
      {Key key,
      @required this.iconPath,
  
})
      : super(key: key);